# open a link on android without address bar

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, web

I  am sending  Push Notification using OneSignal.
When the user clicking  on the push notification, it automaticlly open  a link to my web site.
How can I hide the address bar on the Browser?
I tried this code:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

I putted this  code on my web site inside the `<head>`.
But it's working only when the user add the web site to his homepage.

Comment: add a web client in your android app

Answer (score 1):

Android browser is WebKit based

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```